# jQuery click event is not firing in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to submit the form through a jquery button click event when user **press enter in the textbox**.

Following is my code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $('.buttonComment').live("click", function(e) {
          alert('er');
       });
     });​
</script>

<form>
<input type="text" class="inputComment" id="inputComment<?php echo $msg_id;?>" value=""/>
<input type="submit" class="buttonComment" id="<?php echo $msg_id;?>" value='' />
<i id="iComment<?php echo $msg_id;?>"/>
</form>
```

The above code works nice in Firefox. But with Internet Explorer, it is unable to fire the button click event. Instead its submitting the form.

When I click on the submit button it works fine. But when I press enter while cursor at textbox it does not work properly.

In short I'm trying to achieve the comment system just like Facebook.

[Here is jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6pqLX/)

Comment: you might want to try capturing the form submit event instead of the submit button click event.

Comment: Use input type buttom then if everything was ok submit the form with javascript or you can add return false; in click function. and if everything was ok return true;.

Comment: IE has a known bug over this and especially when it's only one field in the form!

Comment: What version(s) of IE are you testing? (this is an important detail!)

Comment: I also couldn't make it work with IE8.

Comment: Updated my answer with 2 more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this recently! I couldn't believe that it was happening - because the post data was passed correctly!

There was no logical explanation to that and now I must say it's just Internet Explorer unnoticed bug!

### Solution 1

It appears that Internet Explorer scans the page at load time and figures out which submit buttons are visible, then attaches the enter-to-submit functionality to those forms.

To fix this scenario, you can use the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input').keydown(function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
        return false;
     }
   });
});
```

The return false is rather important in Internet Explorer, because it prevents that beep that you might hear if you hit return. The beep is saying "you can't hit enter here!", but return false cancels the key press and therefore the browser won't warn.

Read more about this and what people say: [Submit a Form in IE with Enter](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter)

### Solution 2

The other solution could be but it didn't work in my case is to add additional hidden input field:

```
<!-- Fix for Internet Explorer bug (One text input and submit, disables submit on pressing "Enter") -->
  <div style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="hiddenText"/>
  </div>
```

### Solution 3

Another solution is to detected the user's browser and if it's Internet Explorer cancel enter key and force user to click submit button for proper submitting.

```
function browserIE(){
   if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8){   // Let's detect if it's Internet Explorer 8 or lower
     return true;
 }
  return false;
```

}

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) { // Bind keyboard events
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13' && browserIE()){ // When user hits 'enter key' (keyCode 13) and only when the browser is Internet Explorer version 8 or lower
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
});
```

That is the only way to force Internet Explorer user to click submit button to perform proper submit, because, as I mentioned before hitting enter being on the field wouldn't make proper submit and just would ended up with simple page reload!

[jsFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/htALk/)

Also Recommend reading: [Button versus Input[type="submit"] in Internet Explorer and beyond](http://ajaxian.com/archives/button-versus-inputtypesubmit-in-ie-and-beyond)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button has `type="submit"`. You have to mention this in IE; In Chrome and Firefox this seems to be the default type.

I am using this and it works fine everywhere. Try the form submit handler rather than the click:

```
<form id="1234">
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="asdasd" >Button </button>
</form>

<script>
   $("#1234").submit(function(){
      alert("Hello World");
   })
</script>
```

Comment: I also thought so but in my case it didn't work. Nice call though!;)

Comment: I edited my answer. Listening to the submit event seems to be universal

Comment: the first one work in IE 9 but not in any prev versions. Joys of cross browser madness :/

Comment: Just like Google, I stopped support for browser Internet Explorer < 8. Don't even want to remember about this `pain in all places` called previous versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: me too. But i think it works if you use <button type="submit"> and not <input type='submit'>

Comment: Only in some cases it could be important. I emphasized it with this article: http://ajaxian.com/archives/button-versus-inputtypesubmit-in-ie-and-beyond